# docker "Cannot mkdir: Permission denied"

Tags: docker, linux

I'm trying to run wordpress inside docker.

I've been following this tutorial : https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-the-official-docker-wordpress-image/

But when I run this command :

```
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx -d --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 -v "$PWD/":/var/www/html wordpress
```

The container crashes, and in the logs I can see things like :

```
tar: ./wp-admin: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
```

Comment: In order to check it if that directory exists and its permissions, execute `ls -la $PWD` PS:This should be a comment but I do not have enough rep Are you sure you are in the right directory?

Comment: Have you been tried to use absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, i'll answer myself here I guess.

The problem was, I had "broken" volumes.

So, I've made a little script to "reset" docker and install wordpress.
Careful it removes everything.

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove images
docker rmi $(docker images -q)  
# remove containers
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)    
# remove volumes
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)

echo "Type mysql root password : "
read mspass

docker run --name wordpressdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$mspass -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress -d mysql:5.7

docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$mspass --name wordpress --link wordpressdb:mysql -p 127.0.0.2:8080:80 -v "$PWD/":/var/www/html -d wordpress
```

Comment: What do you mean with broken volumes?

Comment: I don't really know, it's just when I removed them everything worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Try to run such command as root or grant user and group rights to the folder with chown.

That's only what comes to my mind for now.

Comment: I'm running it as root yes.
And used chmod 777 on the folder I wanted to link

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps information like
1) the docker host OS details (RHEL, Centos, Ubuntu, etc)
2) the mounted directory permission (ls -al)
would help to debug this issue...

This could be an SELinux issue as well, so disable SELinux and try